# Link Google Developer Account With Google Cloud Account

Tags: android, google-cloud-platform, google-developers-console, google-play-developer-api

I'm trying to connect google developer account with google cloud account in order to use one of it's services,
but my live application is using different google cloud account from google developer account.

How can I link developer account with different cloud account, is there any way to solve this?

Comment: Are you using the same identity?

Comment: What identity?! @JohnHanley

Comment: The identity that you log into your account with.